# VSCode get "Could not establish connection to "SERVER": Downloading VS Code Server failed - please install either curl or wget on the remote."

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I have installed vscode server and successfully opened it. But when I try to open it again, it says: Downloading VS Code Server failed - please install either curl or wget on the remote.

I tried to re-install the .vscode-server but the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `curl` or `wget`.

For instructions on how to install `curl` on windows, mac or linux, please see link below:

[Install Curl on Windows, Linux and MacOs](https://help.ubidots.com/en/articles/2165289-learn-how-to-install-run-curl-on-windows-macosx-linux)

For instructions on how to install `wget` on windows or mac, please see link below:

[Install Wget on Windows and MacOs](https://techpp.com/2022/03/05/install-and-use-wget-on-mac-windows-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was installing tar (`$sudo dnf install tar -y`).

I had curl and wget already installed. Read the debug console; the script complained it couldn't see the tar command when it tried to unzip some downloaded packages while it was installing vscode server.

I am running Rocky Linux 9.